# IDENTITY_INSERT is ON but I get an SqlException saying it is OFF

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

This is my code :

```
public class OrderItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MovieId")]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public Movie? Movie { get; set; }
}
```

and the migration :

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "OrderItems",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Amount = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    Price = table.Column<double>(type: "float", nullable: false),
                    MovieId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    OrderId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_OrderItems", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_OrderItems_Movies_MovieId",
                        column: x => x.MovieId,
                        principalTable: "Movies",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_OrderItems_Orders_OrderId",
                        column: x => x.OrderId,
                        principalTable: "Orders",
                        principalColumn: "Id");
                });
```

For me it is clear that identity is on but I get this error :

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'OrderItems' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

In SQL Server Management Studio, it works just fine.

I tried to execute a SQL command before adding a new item but nothing has changed.

```
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("SET IDENTITY_INSERT OrderItems ON");
await _context.OrderItems.AddAsync(orderItem);
```

Comment: why do you want to set a auto increment field and where do you get the error?

Comment: @nbk I get the error when the user confirms his order

Comment: @TudorG i undestand that, but you need to show the code, that produces the error

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an `IDENTITY` column in SQL Server, you need to add an additional annotation to your class:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MovieId")]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public Movie? Movie { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you could also specify this in FluentAPI configuration, if you prefer.

This tells EF that this is an identity column, and as long as you don't set it to any value in your C# code before saving a new entity to the database table, it'll be handled properly by EF and SQL Server.

See the [official MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations) for more details.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I want to specify that I don't get this error for my other models.